# Finding the Maclaurin series of a given function knowing another Maclaurin series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Using the Maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$, compute the Maclaurin series for:
$$\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}$$.

What is the interval of convergence of this series?

Once you get the Maclaurin series for the function, I know how to find the convergence interval (I can use the Ratio test here, I believe) but how would I find the Maclaurin series for that using the one given?

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}x^n$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{1+x}{1+x^2} = (1+x)\dfrac1{1+x^2}=(1+x)\dfrac1{1-(-x^2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

> We obtain:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}}
> &=(1+x)\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-x^2)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^jx^{2j}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^jx^{2j+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{j}{2}\right\rfloor} x^{j}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1+x-x^2-x^3+x^4+x^5-\cdots}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (2) we multiply out.
- In (3) we use the *[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to determine the correct sign.